# Cisco ISE migration to Azure cloud

Tags: cisco, authentication, cisco-ise, authorization

I would like to if any one has migrated Cisco ISE to Azure. Any challenges faced, how migration planis done.

Currently using ISE with 
Administration Persona - 2 VMs
Monitoring Persona - 2 VM's
Policy Service Persona - 4 VM's

Version- 2.3.0.298
Installed Patches - 1,2
Product Identifier (PID) - ISE-VM-K9
Version Identifier (VID)- V01
ADE-OS Version - 3.0.3.030

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, ISE is not supported running natively on any cloud platform.

For the currently latest release (ISE 2.7), Cisco [lists the following supported virtual environments](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/2-2/compatibility/ise_sdt.html#pgfId-207652):

> Cisco ISE supports the following virtual environment platforms:
>
> - VMware ESXi 5. x (5.1 U2 and later support RHEL 7), 6. x
> - KVM on RHEL 7.0
> - Microsoft Hyper-V on Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 and later

If you were doing this on AWS, you could try something like [VMware on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/vmware/) to run an ESXi hypervisor to run ISE on. With Azure you can try running nested Hyper-V servers, but I wouldn't feel comfortable recommending this.

In a recent fully virtualized AWS deployment, we ended up running ISE on rented co-located servers connected through IPSec VPNs to our AWS environment. Not ideal, but at least it's fully supported.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I will check more on nested Hypher-V for azure.

How was your migration done, can you please explain more.